# Typeerror: Unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'ÿ'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have found this code (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TGuTPjfiV4r7ra_5eLMkbXBnesYlvTyT) written by Adafruit (and modified by me to add in a few extra features which work in python 2.7, when I try to run the code in python 3 to make it easier to develop (as I haven't looked at much python 2 before) it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Forecast-Printer/forecast.py", line 55, in <module>
    printer = Adafruit_Thermal("/dev/serial0", 19200, timeout=5)
  File "/home/pi/Forecast-Printer/Adafruit_Thermal.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.wake()
  File "/home/pi/Forecast-Printer/Adafruit_Thermal.py", line 605, in wake
    self.writeBytes(255)
  File "/home/pi/Forecast-Printer/Adafruit_Thermal.py", line 189, in writeBytes
    super(Adafruit_Thermal, self).write(chr(arg))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 518, in write
    d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 63, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'ÿ'
```

The code is run on a raspberry pi running raspbian (GUI version) and it needs to be run with `sudo` as it communicates with the mini thermal printer via serial.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

edit:
Here is some code that triggers the same error when run in python 3:

```
from Adafruit_Thermal import *

printer = Adafruit_Thermal("/dev/serial0", 19200, timeout=5)
```

Comment: just a hunch: you could try `super(Adafruit_Thermal, self).write(arg)` as binary streams need binary data, not str

Comment: You're going to have to show us a [mcve] if you want us to debug your code. If you want to debug it yourself, the answer is just that you can't call a function that wants bytes (as `super().write` presumably does) with strings, but `chr` returns a string. If `arg` is a number from 0 to 255, you want to create the equivalent single-byte `bytes` object (`bytes([arg])` will do it); if it's a number from 0 to 1.1M, you want to decide how you want to encode your text to bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace it looks like when the printer is initialized, the Adafruit library wakes up the printer by writing the integer `255` over serial to the printer. It does this by calling the `Serial` class's `write()` method (inside its own `write_bytes()` method) on line 189:

`super(Adafruit_Thermal, self).write(chr(arg))`

It's able to do this since the `Adafruit_Thermal` class inherits from `Serial`, as you can see in the class definition.

Well as @abarnert pointed out, `chr()` returns a string, but it sounds like `write()` is expecting binary data. So I'd try both the suggestions in the comments to your question. First try changing line 189 to:

`super(Adafruit_Thermal, self).write(arg)`

If that doesn't work try:

`super(Adafruit_Thermal, self).write(bytes([arg]))`

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, but what does the b'\xc3\xbf' line do and how do I use it?

Comment: if you update your question with some example code we might be able to figure that out

Comment: can you link to the code for Adafruit_Thermal library that you're using? i don't see any code at the google drive link.

Comment: updated the answer based on looking at the Adafruit_Thermal library, and on the suggestions to your original question